# Question marks instead of special characters when running cypress on ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8, special-characters, cypress, openstack

I am using an ubuntu instance to run my cypress tests to offload the computation load.  But the special characters are coming out as `?`.  For example, running `npx cypress run` on my own machine gives:

```
 ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │ Cypress:    5.6.0                                                       │
 │ Browser:    Electron 85 (headless)                                      │
 │ Specs:      11 found (my spec files here)                               │
 └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But on my ubuntu instance, I get this:

```
  ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
  ? s:  0                                                                        ?
  ? Video:        true                                                           ?
  ? Duration:     33 seconds                                                     ?
  ? Spec Ran:     connections/connectionstable.spec.js                           ?
  ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

I know this is a totally cosmetic thing, but its bothering me.  The `✓` and `x` characters also show up as `?`, though they do indeed show up in the correct colors (green and red).

I am using an openstack instance with a company-internal ubuntu image, but I don't see a whole lot of info to put here about the image, just that its 2021.

I tried putting `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8` in the terminal, and adding it to the `.bashrc`, as suggested in [Foreign characters won't display in SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/foreign-characters-wont-display-in-ssh)
, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: How something is rendered is controlled by the terminal and affected by the available/configured fonts. What cypress outputs would rather be a case for a bug report. As you say yourself, this is not about the code which is the same.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, right, I undestand that. So how can I configure the terminal in the openstack ubuntu instance to show these characters properly like they are shown on my local machine?

Comment: Find out what the software involved is, on both machines. Compare their versions, configurations and how they are invoked. Compare any debug output you can retrieve from them. Possibly, run them using `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix that, in my case I was running the cypress through a Gradle task in IntelliJ.
I had to edit the Gradle configuration run and set the: Environment Variable to: **LC_CTYPE=UTF-8**

[image: Image of Gradle Run/Debug Configurations]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not running cypress through a gradle task in IntelliJ.  I am running them on an openstack Ubuntu-20 instance using Jenkins.  I would have no idea how to apply your solution to my environment.

Comment: try to set ubuntu environment variable as described here:
https://mkyong.com/linux/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu/